# Adding row data in spreadsheet using pyexcel

Tags: python

I'm trying to add row data using `pyexcel`. In the cookbook I have found a method called `update_rows()` it takes three arguments (`fileToRead`, `list/dictionary`, `outputFile`)
I get the following error: `NotImplementedError: We do not overwrite files`

I can see that this is not the method I'm looking for. I'm open to any module making use of `.ods` format if it better suits my needs.

```py
import os
import pyexcel
import pyexcel.ext.ods
from pyexcel.cookbook import update_rows
import datetime


def mkExcel(dataList, tDate, pathToFile):
    whereToGo = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(pathToFile), "Archive_%s.ods") % tDate

    if not os.path.exists(whereToGo):
        dataList = pyexcel.utils.dict_to_array(dataList)
        # "output.xls" "output.xlsx" "output.ods" "output.xlsm"
        dataList = pyexcel.Sheet(dataList)
        print
        dataList
        dataList.save_as(whereToGo)
    else:
        dSheet = pyexcel.load(whereToGo, name_columns_by_row=0)
        dataList = pyexcel.utils.dict_to_array(dataList)

        custom_row = {"Row -1": [11, 12, 13]}
        ## update_rows(existing.ods, custom_row, new.ods)
        update_rows(dSheet, custom_row, whereToGo)


now = datetime.datetime.now()
now = '%s-%s-%s' % (now.year, now.month, now.day)

example_dict = {"Column 1": [1, 2, 3], "Column 2": [4, 5, 6], "Column 3": [7, 8, 9]}

here = os.getcwd()
mkExcel(example_dict, now, here)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am the owner of pyexcel and have updated documentation regarding [your use case](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial_file.html). More details on row manipulation can be found in api referance [Sheet.Row](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.Sheet.row.html#pyexcel.Sheet.row).

Here's a copy of the example code to **add a new row**:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> import pyexcel.ext.xls
>>> sheet = pe.get_sheet(file_name="example.xls")
>>> sheet # just to show what the sheet contains
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | 4        | 7        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        | 5        | 8        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 3        | 6        | 9        |
+----------+----------+----------+
>>> sheet.row += [12, 11, 10] # now add it to its row
>>> sheet.save_as("new_example.xls") # save it to a new file
>>> pe.get_sheet(file_name="new_example.xls") # read it back
Sheet Name: pyexcel
+----------+----------+----------+
| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 1        | 4        | 7        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 2        | 5        | 8        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 3        | 6        | 9        |
+----------+----------+----------+
| 12       | 11       | 10       |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

If you would like to use other libraries, [odfpy](https://github.com/eea/odfpy) and [ezodf](https://github.com/T0ha/ezodf) are what you might consider.

Comment: One could not ask for a better answer. Nor from a better source than from the owner. I tried to vote up your answer but haven't the reputation points to do so. I will as soon as I do.  As for another library, Im quite happy to stick with Pyexcel. I will eventually play with others im sure but not for this project. I find your lib to be easy to work with. Well documented to. I knew the answer would be so simple that I would kick myself for not seeing it!   Funny thing, I was dreaming of code when I herd my phone whistle, awoke to find my problem solved. Thank you very much CHFW.

Comment: That's fine. My library is intended for data processing involving multiple excel files that usually are mixed(messed) up by different file formats, and accidentally it provides a simple interface for the same job involving a single file format. If you need to work with Fonts, Formulas, Styles and Images, you shall not use my library. Other than that, feature requests are welcome.

Comment: chfw, Where would one add a feature request? As in maintaining key order as declared order, not dictionary order?

Comment: chfw your library is excellent and has made my life and job a lot easier, thanks. @thisGuyDidSomethingOnce between pyexcel and openpyxl I've been able to get everything I've ever thought possible done when using them both in combination together. Functionality + Formatting with both.